# adding items to selecteditems

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm getting an odd "An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'" every time I try to add items to a listpicker.selecteditems. Here's the code:

```
if (wine != null)
{
    foreach (string s in wine.Varietal.Split(';'))
    {
        var selectedTip = (from item in tips where item.Name == s select item).FirstOrDefault();
        if (selectedTip != null)
        {
                varietalListPicker.SelectedItems.Add(selectedTip);
        }
    }
}
```

selectedTip is not null and appears correct but not sure why the debugger says null reference exception. Code seems to work fine for single select list but for multi select I don't really know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer why this isn't working is kind of simple: the SelectedItems property is read-only. You'd have to add a setter to this property.

I think I found a [useful blog entry](http://community.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2012/02/02/how-to-databind-selecteditems-of-the-listpicker-and-recurringdayspicker.aspx) for you. Just jump to the section "Extending the ListPicker to Support Setting of SelectedItems" to find how you can modify the SelectedItems property right.